# Scrapy response is an Invalid/Unknown String

Tags: python, web-scraping, encoding, server, scrapy

Good day, I'm having some issues with  a scrapy script I wrote.
The code works perfectly on my local machine, but when I run it on an ubuntu server, I'm getting response like this

```
c\x00�^\x00@6Us�e�yV�\x17~J��'\x1d$B2c�����5��F8\x10��M#[�(\nxm��C���p�\x05R [��\x00\x02v`,/�\x00��˛��Pv�p+ �1\rgq�p��\x15��\x18�/��\x01mQ
```

Response code is ok. But the text is the above unreadable sequence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting compressed data.

Remove the `Accept-Encoding` line from your headers and try again.

If it doesn't work try to set `Accept-Encoding: deflate`.