# Scrapy parsed unknown character

Tags: python-requests, scrapy

I have wanted to scrape the site https://www.bikebd.com/brand/yamaha/ . here is my script

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

from urllib.parse import urlencode


class BikebdSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'bikebd'
    allowed_domains = ['www.bikebd.com']
    headers = {
            'accept': '*/*',
            'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,da;q=0.8',
            'cache-control':'no-cache',
            'cookie': '_ga=GA1.1.1549289426.1669609851; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjhCN1BnV0RoK3dOQnFEQlhYRUZVZEE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiTFQ4Ym15MWhoU1hmR3FxaWdVYnkvbnovMTVDbS9iRm1OVCsrV0F2RzA5dHlmMWpObENoSFBWY0VXclBNWkZaNlV1aitwSXBWNjhNMGs2Z3JqQ3ZvQWVIQ25QcnNOZkNpR3lwMGNkL01aWHM3VDZ5YmZJblRha0kyUk5IMTh2UzQiLCJtYWMiOiJjMzFmMDZlZDFjNzVhNTVlZjY1MWEzNWJkZjY5Y2Q1MjFiZmNmM2UxOWRiZWJlMGRhZWY5OGU0MGQ4OWI5N2ViIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; bikebd_session=eyJpdiI6ImVVb2NqcmFLR2dKSXc2NnNqUlV6ZWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibUVNcEZidUxsbWdkK3c2UDFYdDYwcHFOdVU1WmVXY0ZiV1pHRzJBbzlaUDNuWGl2Vk1OTk5QYnRkdmVXdDg3bEx2SEpiMGE1c2dvakdkU0tQOTBucHc5ajRpcGpod2ViL3B2ME9DRXc4SUFtSG56YU9MVTdEVi9rYW8reXk0TDYiLCJtYWMiOiI5MmU2NWEyZDhkOGFiNTdkYzQ0ZGJhMDQwNzFhYzFmOGY4MzNjNWU2ODczYWNiOTVlNjU4MWUyZWVmMzE5NjNmIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; _ga_HEG073JLWK=GS1.1.1670663205.2.1.1670663540.0.0.0',
            'pragma': 'no-cache',
            'referer': 'https://www.bikebd.com/bike-price-in-bd',
            'sec-ch-ua': '"Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"',
            'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
            'sec-ch-ua-platform': "Windows",
            'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
            'sec-fetch-mode': 'no-cors',
            'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
            }

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ["https://www.bikebd.com/brand/yamaha"]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url= url ,  callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        container = response.xpath("//div[@class='tab-cards-rev']/div/div[@class='col-md-3']")
        for item in container:
            title = item.xpath(".//h2[@class='ltn-tittle mb-0']/strong/text()").get()

            yield {'title' : title}
```

but when I crawl the script it returns none. Then I start debug the spider with open in browser by this line of code...

```
def parse(self, response):
    open_in_browser(response)
```

Then it showed me some unreadable characters like below.

```
ôÿ‘šôC@#tøœ÷ÿfjun_N?ÈKÛžDÜ$YVyË²UÒ–³TUoŸÄ'…8hI®ö,ëá4·9g¶åÝûtÎOûUéCh|â¢€Ð8`÷ D“†b&³“ÝªW¯ª~÷À"Á¹¹a]Ðøß¿{©wŽ(€è  ¼ÇX¶nû»¥ˆŠ¦eÙËÿ«Íñ"åY³1Vÿõ¯³½ÍUDÃ±‡½â`¹‰½é½ê”§Œl‡%,{Š»È?8PaÐ-œ[·EÏ&Žl,ö‰êµŽÄ€ŠŒ+ŒMØèãG{L˜ž2 ?£?èaÂ´UWÞ$[0²üÃZ’‡N±ÅÔ%$[pÝ9ä[ ¯±ÖÞW(ñ¥-ˆxf¿ì±
```

What's going on the site? need some help.

Comment: [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69777414/16429780)